# Locating a Web Element in a Drop-down list by Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

Selenium Python Locator

I use Selenium in Python to to some auto-clicking task for me. The thing is I got this drop-down list, which do not let me send any keys, only select 1 of the option from the list.

I tried to use `browser.find_element` to search for it by the option I want which named **"Deplacement_X1(5)"** by 7 locators(`id,name,xpath,link test, partial link text, tag name, class name, css selector`) but it didn't work.

Full of the option's element is :

```
<li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters css-18wioi6" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-value="175155">Deplacement_X1(5)
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
</li>
```

I'm not a web dev, can anyone give me an instruction or a command to locate this?

Comment: Without know the website, maybe the solution is click the parent element that open the drop-drown list, then click element on the list that you want

Comment: Hello Wonka, The parent element is a ul element. I clicked on in and there is smaller list inside. I tried to use the Selenium select by visible text but it won't work with this element. I will try to click on that parent first, then use the link text to find it, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following approaches:

- Selenium's recording feature which would capture your input and turn it to selectors
- Using the `:nth-child(n)` css selector

Answer (score 1):

If you could share the site URL that would be really helpful to answer the question.

```
Since the drop down is in <li> you could use the click() on <ul> to expand the drop down and use nth-child() to click the desired option from <li>.
```